# How to measure the strength of association between binary variables where the majority of values is zero?

Tags: independence, binary-data, association-measure

I have two binary variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$, which take value in {0, 1}. The overwhelming majority of their values are 0. I wanted to know if there is a way to appropriately measure their association given that the majority of their values are zero. Note that I am also opened to dependence tests as well.

I was looking at the *phi* coefficient, but it seems at a high level, the *phi* coefficient is proportional to the product of the agreements minus the product of the disagreements. In my data set, intuitively, I get the sense, thus, that the *phi* coefficient will likely be very large.

Are there more appropriate association measures or independence tests for this type of data?

Comment: You could, perhaps with some profit, characterize your data differently: you have a two-way table giving the counts of $(X_1,X_2)$ equal to $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,1)$.  The first count is much larger than the rest and the last is much smaller--but so what?  There does not seem to be anything special about this table, so why not apply an appropriate measure of association for two-way tables?

Comment: whuber is correct as long as you have more than 5 1,1s (I imagine the rarest event). You were on the right track using the phi coefficient, but as a measure of the association, not a test.

Comment: thank you both. that definitely helps with some confidence with where i am going.